# Why am I getting 400 error when I query from an API?

Tags: python, https, payload

I have a list of company names at my disposal. I am trying to get more information from them using public data that is available at `https://5500search.dol.gov/search"`. For eg: I am trying to get information on "CVS". I will  change the `payload = make_payload("CSV")` in the following code. This will give me a json file with necessary information. This information is what I get when I use the search using the website. But when I try to search on other companies like `Vyve Broadband LLC` using the code, I get the 400 error. But  I am able to get a list when I use the website's search bar directly. Why is that so? I am very new to all this. So, I would really appreciate some insights on how to query properly from an API.

````
import requests
import json

URL = "https://5500search.dol.gov/search"
def make_payload(plan):
    payload = {"q": f"plansponsor:{plan}"}
    return payload

payload = make_payload("Vyve Broadband LLC")

resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload)
print(resp.json())```
````

Comment: If you look at the response, how does your request body compare to the same request made via a browser?

Comment: Did you not scroll to the end of the response? `'msg': "no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param", 'code': 400}}`

Answer (score 1):

The 400 response code means that the request body has an invalid syntax. You should consult the API documentation and follow the guidelines on creating a request. Most APIs are very rigorous on the formatting of requests, **I recommend using software like [Postman](http://postman.com/downloads/) to get the proper syntax for your API requests.**

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the format of `payload`. You need the key (name) of the parameter `make_payload` as well as the value `Vyve Broadband LLC`.

Refer to https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

I rewrote the function to produce the correct format required by that API:

```
import requests
import json

URL = "https://5500search.dol.gov/search"
def make_payload(plan):
    payload = {"make_payload": plan}
    return payload

payload = make_payload("Vyve Broadband LLC")

resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload)
print(resp.json())
```